# fast concatenation of large number of files on linux

Tags: linux, concatenation

I'm looking for a fast way to concatenate together large number of files from a single directory, approximately 50,000 or more files. Each file size ranges between 1 to 5 Mb. I know doing this only once can be not so time consuming using find or cat command. But I'm running a program which iteratively updates some of this files and than I have to concatenate all files all over again to make a single file database. Also some times program creates new files in the directory which may increase the total number of file to be concatenated every time process is repeated. As, I have to go through this step multiple times iteratively the computation time for concatenation will be gradually increasing with increase in number and size of the files from few mins to hours. Currently I'm using find command to do this process. But I was wondering if there are any other better ways to do this process which may take less time (couple of minutes) to concatenate all the files.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you are using your file system as a database.  Re-work your workflow, and use a database.

Comment: What @William has said is probably correct. That said, I imagine there is a way to do something smart on the file system level. It would probably best to use a dedicated partiiton which has nothing than those files and just re-allocate the blocks instead of senselessly moving 50 gig around. Perhaps there are file systems which are simpler structured than others.

Comment: Why do you need such big file? .. could you please give more details about the use case

Comment: Ha, another thought is that it may be cheapest to buy 50 gigs of RAM and work in RAM, syncing in the background only. Although 50 GB is probably not enough for your use case, and at some point you leave the realm of cheap user hardware.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94041/a-virtual-file-containing-the-concatenation-of-other-files

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. However, I think at this point using extra RAM may not be possible. Also may be I think I was not clear enough with what I meant by creating a database from the files. So I may try to explain the issue bit more clearly.

Comment: I am performing an genome analysis during which thousand of files of size 1-5 MB are generated. All this files need to be concatenated together for the program to make single database for all the information in the file. Here what I mean by database is not SQL database, but a flat file database that is specific for the program Im running. However this process is iteratively perfromed as more and more genomes are analyzed and after every analysis some new files are added and some old files are updated with new information.

Comment: So all files has to be re concatenated to make new version of the flat file database. So I m looking for some better approach to do this step where I can reduce the computation time for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`'s [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), you can spare yourself the writing of the concatenation into a disk file by feeding it directly to the program you're running, therewith also parallelizing the concatenation reading and the analyzing process, provided that the concatenation is read sequentially only.
Instead of the filename argument to the analysis program you'd write `<(find … | xargs cat)` (i. e. your find and cat command within the process substitution construct).